# Maven and maven-resources-plugin

Tags: maven

I would like to use maven-resources-plugin to copy resource to another directory.

My resources directory have this structure :

```
log4j.xml
xml
  |_ resource-1
  |_ resource-n
```

I would like to copy only log4.xml to output directory. Here is my plugin code :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${glassfish.conf}</outputDirectory>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>${conf.location}</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/log4j.xml</include>
                    </includes>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/xml/*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>copy-log4j-to-glassfish</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
</plugin>
```

But all is copied to output directory (log4j.xml and xml directory).

I tried

```
<resource>
    <directory>${conf.location}</directory>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/xml/*</exclude>
        </excludes>
</resource>
```

Or

```
<resource>
    <directory>${conf.location}</directory>
    <includes>
        <include>**/log4j.xml</include>
    </includes>                         
</resource>
```

Even

```
<resource>
    <directory>${conf.location}</directory>
    <excludes>
        <exclude>**/*</exclude>
    </excludes>
</resource>
```

But all the content of directory is included...What is the problem ?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer Andrew Logvinov :

With a plugin like that :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-log4j-to-glassfish</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${glassfish.conf}</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${conf.location}</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>log4j.xml</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

it's work well, only log4j.xml is copied.

With this plugin configuration now :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-log4j-to-glassfish</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${glassfish.conf}</outputDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${conf.location}</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>log4j.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

all my files are copied.

I check xsd [here](http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd) are `configuration` block can be inside `plugin` or inside `execution` tag so I don't know if this is a plugin bug or if this misunderstanding of me.

Comment: moving the `configuration` out of `execution` did the trick